# The use of "splitting" in 17th century ironmaking?

Tags: iron

I'm reading a book about spycraft in the 1650s. At that time Sweden was taking over the iron industry so England sent a spy to learn the new technique.

The technique is called "splitting" and it required the construction of a new machine. That is the entire detail the book provides.

Anyone have any idea what this might be?

**UPDATE:** The book is [A History of the British Secret Service](https://books.google.ca/books?id=g2whAQAAIAAJ&q=A%20History%20of%20the%20British%20Secret%20Service&dq=A%20History%20of%20the%20British%20Secret%20Service&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&redir_esc=y). It is not very good, it basically talks about random events and provides few details or background. Its so poor, my copy even left the word "the" out of the title on the cover. Yet widely talked about.

Comment: Might it refer to a skimmer, used to separate iron from slag?

Comment: The correct term is “slitting”. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitting_mill for info on the process and the espionage

Comment: In modern usage, "slitting" is similar. Steel coils ( such as 1500 mm wide with thickness of 10 mm) are slit to narrower widths. The strips are then formed to a round and welded ( ERW) to make pipe and tube: Unless it is seamless , pipe is very likely to be made  with this technique.  Some  narrow slit widths are also use to make flat products.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not related to chemistry. It's about the history of a mechanical process.

Comment: Is metallurgy not chemistry?

Comment: @Andrew - ah, yes, the original text got it wrong! The portion below the lede clearly speaks of the same person, although that is also spelled differently in the book.

Comment: Well, in some wider sense, chemistry is everything from astronomy to psychology. But it does not mean chemistry as science bother with all of that. I would rather day metalurgy, engineering, material science, technology of metal processing and last but not least, history of technology.

Comment: I would include metallurgy with chemistry but slitting isn't metallurgy in my opinion. The ore has already been processed into bar iron, and this is just mechanical processing of the bars to make smaller bits that can be turned into parts like nails. On a side note, I think the confusion about the spying is that Swedish iron was higher quality, but not because of the process. Rather it was the source of the ore (Dannemora) used in Sweden.  So the same "Walloon" process with other ores didn't yield the same quality of iron.

Comment: The question deals with what is generally called "mechanical metallurgy".

Comment: I disagree with the close votes.

Comment: @Poutnik - you fail to conclude your thought - which SE sub is the "proper" one then? I suspect people that know things about the history of ironmaking would be much more likely here than, say, the non-existent "technology of metal processing" sub. The fact that one of the comments comes from "blacksmith37" gives credence to that opinion, as do the many outright answers that are for some reason not put into answers.

Comment: I have not failed to conclude it as I have not intended to. I have been mentioning domains, not SE sites. @blacksmith37 is a retired engineer very close to metallurgy and similar domains.

Comment: How about [hsm.se]?